# Issue in using Zxing via intent if google goggles is installed

Tags: android, zxing, google-goggles

I am using following code to invoke Barcode scanner apps from Zing

```
public Button.OnClickListener mScan = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is if Barcode scanner app is not installed and user has any other scanning app like google goggles i dont get desired result back.This breaks my application.

Is there any way in which i can prevent this ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. call `Intent.setPackage()` with value "com.google.zxing.client.android". This will force it to only accept a response from Barcode Scanner.

Note however that this will make it impossible for other apps to respond, like Barcode Scanner+.

Comment: You could iterate through the result of [`PackageManager.queryIntentActivities`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent,%20int)) and check a whitelist of apps, and then use any valid package name in `Intent.setPackage()`

Comment: thanks this worked what should ideally be a whitelist?? Barcode scanner, Barcode Scanner+ and what else??

Comment: That's all. com.google.zxing.client.android, com.srowen.bs.android and com.srowen.bs.android.simple. I will rewrite the integration code accordingly.

Comment: Just for those interested, if you do want to force Google Goggles the line is 'intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.unveil")`. I'd still encourage the use of the zxing version ..its a great project.

Comment: The OP said that Goggles doesn't reply as expected -- does anyone have more info on that? FYI I incorporated this change into the integrator code: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fandroid-integration%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fintegration%2Fandroid

Comment: @Sean dear respected developer of zxing. is there a way to do not show google goggles as an option on the intent?, because at least my own google goggles app do not recognize QR codes properly

Answer (score 0):

its better to integrate the bar code scanner to your app. Zxing is an open source code you can download it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/). And for the Integration please refer this: http://www.falatic.com/index.php/12/building-zxing-for-android-part-3-using-eclipse. I think this will solve your issue.

Comment: We do not recommend integrating the code like this. It is not necessary to resolve this issue anyway.